# Sequelize findAll where a column value is the same as at least one other item in table

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I currently have the below query which is getting everything that has id = a certain value, but I need it to get only items that have a their column (called Uid) value appear more than once in the table.

Basically I need to filter out items with a unique Uid column value from the result of the below query

```
models.table.findAll({
    where:{
        id: req.params.id
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the SQL query you're looking for would be

```
SELECT id, uid, count(*) FROM table
WHERE id = :id
GROUP BY id, uid
HAVING count(uid) > 1;
```

And in Sequelize it would be:

```
models.table.findAll({
    where: { id: req.params.id },
    group: ['id', 'uid'],
    having: [sequelize.literal('count(?) > ?)', 'uid', 1] 
})
```

Not entirely sure if that is the right syntax for Sequelize. Also look at [sequelize.fn()](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#fnfn-args-sequelizefn) and [sequelize.col()](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#static-method-col).